# Replace any keyboard character(s) with keyboard shortcut or different keystroke

Tags: windows, keyboard, barcode, keyboard-events

For a project using a barcode scanner I need to know if it is possible to replace a special character like

`!
"
§
$
%
=`

with different keyboard strokes like

`arrow down` or `arrow up` or even shortcuts like

`ctrl+a` or `ctrl+v`?

Would be also possible if a specific series of characters resulted in a keystroke/keyboardshortcut, 
for instance this text `InsertArrowLeftHere` would result in this keypress `arrow left`

Is there any way to make something like this work?

Answer (score 0):

A bar-code scanner (unless is used with special hardware in-between) just reads the data, and sends keystrokes to the computer as keyboard interrupts. How the bar-code "string" is interpreted depends on software that, at that moment, has the focus. If you open a Notepad and read something with the barcode scanner, the number will be printed in notepad. In many cases no software comes with the scanner because there is no need for that.

But your software (*the program that **receives** the data from the scanner*) can catch anything typed in the textbox  (or other control that has the focus, for example the whole form can catch the keystrokes). Maybe you can also identify where the keystrokes come from, (means: from which keyboard-input device: keyboard1, keyboard2, barcodescanner etc.) and act accordingly (if from keyboard1 or keyboard2 do nothing, if from barcodescanner then do this).

Comment: sadly this does not work.
there is no software that came with this scanner. I need to find somekind of replace-software that sends keystrokes when a specific character is used. For instance the character ' is replaced with arrow up and * with arrow down.